# angularJS not working with jQuery-Steps plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-steps

The `{{name}}` outside the jquery-steps `div` can be updated, but not the `{{name}}` inside. Why and how to fixed this? Please see my code or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/errkhqdc/).

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!

  <div id="example-basic">
    <h3>Keyboard</h3>
    <section>
        <p>I'm {{name}}</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Effects</h3>
    <section>
        <p>I'm {{name}}</p>
    </section>
</div>  
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';


    $("#example-basic").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true,
    onStepChanging: function(e, currentIndex, newIndex){
    setTimeout(function(){ // Time out included, otherwise throw error.
     $scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.name = 'NEWNAME!'
     console.log($scope.name)// both console and {{name}} outside the #example-basic is updated, but not inside. PROBLEM!
    },10)

    })

    return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Plugins should be initialized in a directive or component...never in a controller

Comment: Also you need to register that controller. Current versions of angular don't allow global functions as controllers

Comment: @charlietfl GOSH, how can a self-study newbie know this..... Can you tell me know to use `.directives` to achieve this?

Comment: should be easy search something like `angular jquery plugin directive`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. What do you mean by "register controller"? Do you mean `myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {  })`?

Comment: yes ...exactly...or pass in a function reference `myApp.controller('myCtrl',MyCtrl)`

Comment: Please people, stop using Angular AND jQuery. Use one or the other. Do things the angular way (DOM generation) OR the jQuery way (DOM manipulation) but not both. You're just mixing up two different technologies with two very different philosophies, that can only lead to clumsier and heavier code, not to mention that you have to load two libraries instead of one.